# I made an error while creating an application in Google Appengine and now I can't use the same Application Identifier. How can i fix this?

Tags: google-app-engine

I made an error while creating an application in **Google Appengine** and now I can't use the same **Application Identifier**. I tried setting a domain name on "Restricted to the following Google Apps domain:" and threw an error and then locked the Application Identifier name.

After which I tried to do the same steps but without messing with **Authentication Options** and it said the application identifier wasn't available now.

But initially it was not a problem.

Help pls :D

Answer (score 1):

Don't get attached to your applications identifiers they are suppose to be internal and not public, just create a new one.

Comment: No, I believe that identifiers are never recycled.

Comment: It is impossible to recycle an App ID.

Comment: Somehow I remember differently, but I checked and you are right.